# Access denied when trying to execute code from the do-file editor

Tags: stata, execution

When I select code in the do-file editor and try to execute it (`Ctrl + D`), I get a pop up saying

> Access to C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\STD06000000.tmp was
>   denied.

However, if I copy the code in the command bar and run it, it runs OK.

I've been looking online for help and I have reinstalled Stata but it didn't work. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some kind of permission problem. It seems odd since it appears Stata was able to write the temp file to the directory but later not able to access it.

You can probably bypass the problem saving the do-file in some other location before running it. (Stata creates and runs a temp file only if you run the do-file without saving it.)

If you don't find a solution here or at statalist.com you should contact Tech Support.

Comment: I have the do file saved in a shared drive (where I also save my outputs). Could that be the problem?